# Imprimir los datos capturados por while

Tags: while, imprimir

vengo a pedir ayuda a este foro para un trabajo de la escuela, mi duda es cómo puedo imprimir los datos que captura "while". Les explico, quiero que al final salgan todos los resultados de las tres asignaturas que capturé, pero solo captura los últimos datos que ingresé. Intenté hacer otro ciclo "while" en donde solo arroje los resultados, pero solo arroja los datos ingresados del último. De antemano gracia, les dejo una captura de mi código, apenas estoy iniciando.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] como mencioné anteriormente

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español, se recomienda copiar el código fuente en *texto* a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Bro estás parcheado tus propias variables en cada pasada del bucle, de modo que para la última vez que introduces datos machacas o sustituyes los de la pasada anterior, si no quieres perder esos datos, puedes guardarlos en otras variables o en casos un poco más avanzados en un array.